# Is any ready made connecter available which reads message from Kafka topic and insert into AWS Neptune?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, amazon-neptune

I need to read kafka topic and store them into Neptune (graph db) using kafka connector.

Or Is there any other way to accomplish the task without writing any language specific code which connect to Neptune db and insert the data?

Comment: If you really don't want to write code, I'd suggest using a tool like Nifi to consume and upload to Neptune's REST API

Comment: We've been discussing creating a Kafka sink / Kinesis consumer mainly for the purposes of taking CDC logs from a relational database and directly inserting/updating Neptune from those stream messages.  A lot of this is dependent on the input format and mapping the data to the graph data model.  Can you give more info on your specific input data structure/format?

Answer (score 0):

I would do that in 2 steps without writing any code

**Step I**

First, get the data from Kafka into csv using logstash https://www.elastic.co/logstash

This can be done without writing code just by configuration. You need to define a data pipeline in logstash using a config file.

[image]

1. Download an logstash from site: https://www.elastic.co/downloads/logstash
2. Unzip
3. In the config folder create a file kafka-tocsv.conf with the below content. Update parameter as per your system configuration

```
input {
 kafka {
 bootstrap_servers => "localhost:9092"
 topics => "test-topic1"
 group_id => "99ds9932"
 }
}
output {
  csv {
    fields => ["@timestamp","message"]
    path => "c:/export.csv"
  }
}
```

4. execute the following command to start the pipeline

```
C:\logstash-7.4.0\bin>logstash.bat -f ..\config\kafka-tocsv.conf
```

Now as and when objects are pushed into the topic you will see those messages logged into the csv file.

Note : for debugging change the config file as shown below to get the information abaout the fields that you want to convert to csv.

```
input {
 kafka {
 bootstrap_servers => "localhost:9092"
 topics => "test-topic1"
 group_id => "99ds9932"
 }
}
output {
  stdout {}
}
```

**Step II**

Currently, the Neptune Output plugin is missing for Logstash.
Either we can Upload the data to Neptune  by using the steps mentioned at url: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/bulk-load-data.html

Or

We can automate the steps by setting up a crone job which will:

1. Periodically execute the pipeline, and upload the csv to s3 bucket as mentioned in link. Prerequisite : aws cli must be installed and aws credentials should be configured on the system

```
aws s3 cp data-file-name s3://bucket-name/object-key-name
```

Invokes the nepune loader

```
curl -X POST \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    https://your-neptune-endpoint:port/loader -d '
    {
      "source" : "s3://bucket-name/object-key-name",
      "format" : "format",
      "iamRoleArn" : "arn:aws:iam::account-id:role/role-name",
      "region" : "region",
      "failOnError" : "FALSE",
      "parallelism" : "MEDIUM",
      "updateSingleCardinalityProperties" : "FALSE",
      "queueRequest" : "TRUE",
      "dependencies" : ["load_A_id", "load_B_id"]
    }'
```

Comment: I assume the OP is looking for continuous, streaming uploads, not manual, bulk ones, since that answer is the same regardless of what technology is used

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer for point out that step 2 can be automated via a crone performing s3 upload and vpc endpoint invocation. But yes that will still be an automated bulk operation, not a streamed one. Updated the answer accordingly

Comment: Cron wouldn't be accurate, because there's no easy way to prevent duplicates and that assumes logstash is writing to unique files between each invocation

Comment: Besides that, Kafka Connect has an S3 sink, so don't need to do any copying or use logstash

Comment: Wow, that's interesting, I wasn't aware of that, let me have look.

Comment: Seems it will not be straight if we use Kafka Connect . If we upload the records directly to s3 from Kafka then those will be JSON (I assume) and the formats supported via Nepune Loaders are csv (Gremlin), ntriples, nquads, turtle, and rdfxml (RDF).

Comment: JSON is one option. The `format.class` config is a pluggable interface

Comment: Thanks for answering.. and apology for late reply.
I was thinking this way…
1. Read kafka topic and put data in s3 using (s3 connector)
2. run neptune loader which read data from s3 and insert into neptune.